# How to let debugger print console logs (SQL) when it's on break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core with `optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory);` enabled

I'm debugging code which has e.g 5 sql queries in a row

```
var a = _context.Something1.ToList();
var b = _context.Something2.ToList();
var c = _context.Something3.ToList();
var d = _context.Something4.ToList();
var e = _context.Something5.ToList();
```

but the thing is that when I have break point on `var a = ...` and then I push "F10" to execute this line and jump into `var b = ...` then logger do not manage to print whole query from `var a = ...` yet - e.g it prints only 1/3 of it, and then it will print the rest.

how can I let it print whole log before I execute `var b = ...`?

Or maybe there are better methods to see raw SQL?

Comment: I usually put break points on each line.  The use F5 instead of stepping.

Comment: Make sure you are using debug not release configuration.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would the logger "print" anything from a breakpoint just because you are using `optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory)`? If you were going to log something, wouldn't you need to be explicitly calling a logger object? Are you sure you are not simply referring to the debugger inspector or something like that?

Comment: @robbpriestley Let's say that you've break point on `Console.WriteLine("text");` then you push e.g F10 button and then "text" appears on Console

Comment: Yes, but I don't see either that or anything to do with logging in your code sample above. I really think you need to clarify your question. Can you be more specific? Can you provide more details? What exactly do you mean by "print"?